# What are cases when thread called await method differs from thread after await?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

In CLR via C# there is a statement : "thread completing code going after await method can differ from thread before"
That is one of reason why lock with await inside is not allowed .
But as i know await doesn't create dedicated thread, it uses 1 current thread and state machine (so 1 thread does it all asynchronous).
So , what are cases it can happen?

Comment: *"as I know await doesn't create dedicated thread, it uses 1 current thread and state machine (so 1 thread does it all asynchronous)"* -- Do you mean that the asynchronous operation uses the current thread continuously from start to finish? Where did you get this information from? Could you edit the question and link to your sources?

Comment: What is "it"? Continuation on same thread or different thread? And why would you care? (Outside UI programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But as i know await doesn't create dedicated thread, it uses 1 current thread and state machine (so 1 thread does it all asynchronous).

The first part of this sentence is true: `await` doesn't cause a dedicated thread. The second part is incorrect; there is a state machine, but there is no guarantee it will all run on one thread.

As I describe in my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), the default behavior is that `await` will capture a context and will resume executing on that context. This context is `SynchronizationContext.Current` (or, if it is `null`, `TaskScheduler.Current`). Most of the time in actual code the context is either a UI synchronization context (resuming on the same UI thread) or a thread pool context (resuming on any available thread pool thread).

> What are cases when thread called await method differs from thread after await?

Any time there isn't a context that resumes on the same thread, `await` could resume on another thread.

Perhaps the simplest example is a Console application; it doesn't have a synchronization context, so the `await` will resume on a thread pool thread. Also, since the main thread is not a thread pool thread, the following code is *guaranteed* to resume on a different thread:

```
async Task Main()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```